# Scrollbar scroll 'size'

Tags: css

How would I, instead of 'scrolling' as much height as I want, a fixed height?

I.e a div is `50px` high and each time I scroll down I want to go down `50px` instead of just 'stopping' where you want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 50px is what you want but it is not what you want? sorry I'm confused.

Comment: It's an example, each time you hold the scrollbar thumb and point the mouse down you would go 50px down (for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can override scrolling of the div in such a way:

```
$("#scrollableContainer").scroll(function(e) {
    //measure how far are you from the top of the scrollable container
    var top = $("#scrollableContainer").scrollTop();

    var scrollIncrement = 50; //50px

    if (top % scrollIncrement!= 0) {
        var delta;
        //calculate delta you need to align the position with
        if(e.detail > 0) {
            //scroll down
            delta = ((top / scrollIncrement) + 1) * scrollIncrement) - top;
        }else {
            //scroll up
            delta = ((top / scrollIncrement) - 1) * scrollIncrement) - top;
        }

        $("#scrollableContainer").scrollTop(delta);
    }
});
```